# Use python variables in a external js file. Django

Tags: javascript, django

I'm working in a Django project and I would like to have it tidy. Thus I decided (among other things) don't have de `css styles` and `js scripts` inside the `html templates`. With the `css styles` I have no problems, I have created a css folder inside the static folder and I save all my `css files` inside, it works perfectly.

My problem comes when I want to do the same with the `js files` that works with the `python` variables that comes from the `views.py`. Because it don't recognise they. How can I import this variables to the `js` external files?

Now I have this, but it don't works.

**main.html**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title> {% block title%}{% endblock%} </title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "/css/main.css" %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "/css/data.css" %}">

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> WELCOME HOME </h1>
        <p>{{Data}}</p>

        /* This script has to be in a external js file. HERE WORKS
        <script>
            alert('{{Data}}');
        </script>*/

        {% block content %}{% endblock%}

        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/js/data.js" %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**data.js**

```
alert('{{Data}}')
//alert({{Data}}) ERROR
```

If the alert has no python variables like `alert("Hello world")` it works well, but when I pass a Python variable it shows '{{Data}}'.

Thank you!

Comment: please go through this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script

Comment: what the django version you are using?

Comment: version 2.2.5. I had read this link before but I can't see how externalise the js file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we can do this in two ways..

1.

add the below line in  your html file

```
{{ value|json_script:"mydata" }}
```

and fetch the above value to data.js file as below

```
var value = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('mydata').textContent);
```

2.

add the following tag at the below of  this line

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var data= '{{ data }}' 
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/token.js' %}"> 
   </script>
```

and you can fetch it like as usual javascript variable as follows
in data.js file

```
 alert(data);
```

Comment: The second option doesn't work, this `var` only will work inside the actual template. You are not exporting it to the new file `token.js`

Comment: enclose the  "/js/data.js"  line with single quotes like '/js/data.js' in this tag < script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/data.js' %}"></script>

Comment: where is the mistake?

Comment: in this line   <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/js/data.js" %}"></script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202341/discussion-between-nea-and-kabali).

Comment: put this line     <script type="text/javascript"> var data= '{{ data }}' </script> above this line  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/data.js' %}"></script>

Comment: The second one worked well. And a simple solution vs getting into ajax

Answer (score 1):

you can pass it through function

try this

html :

```
demo({{var}})
```

js :

```
demo(var){
    alert(var)
}
```

hope it helps